# Exclusive Job Listings

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I discovered after the fact that a job that I applied to was an exclusive job listing that SO ...

> `only shows this job to select candidates`

If I navigate to the SO Jobs main page in a random way on a random date, how would I know which ones are an exclusive job listing?

Answer (score 17):

These "exclusive" job listings are what we call **private jobs**. These allow employers to message potential candidates about a job without having to also post them on our job board. This means that you probably received a message from one of the employers on our platform, and he or she attached the job to their message. You then clicked the name of the job in the message, and saw that banner:

[image]

You won't find these types of jobs through our jobs board, although they look as if they are part of it.

We created these types of jobs so that recruiters will always include relevant information about a job when they message you.